# cakephp reduce quantity stock for every order

Tags: cakephp, sql-update, e-commerce

I develop an ecommerce website. When the user order an items, it will update the order_items table (model: OrderItem) for order_id, product_id and quantity.

But now, I want to update the products table everytimes the order has been make:

product.balance_quantity = product.balance_quantity - orderItem.quantity.

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

On success of order_items update query, shot one more query to update products table with your condition product.balance_quantity = product.balance_quantity - orderItem.quantity as shown below:

```
$this->Product->updateAll(array('Product.balance_quantity' => 'product.balance_quantity - orderItem.quantity'), array('Product.id' => product_id));
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I tried use those updateAll. but i got Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. Any idea why i got those error? thanks in advance.